# SQL: Reverse Position of String

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having below data,trying to delete duplicate rows from table. For example:ab=ba,cd=dc..

Please suggest.

```
ab
ac
ad
ba
bc
bd
da
db
dc
ea
eb
ec
ed
fa
fb
fc
fd
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sort the data - find out the first occurrence - delete the rest

Comment: Edit your question and provide additional information:  (1) what is the database you are using; (2) what results do you want; (3) are your values in one column or two? (4) what have you tried?

Comment: Which one do you want to keep of ab and ba?

Comment: You can find the enries you want to delete by SQL query with table `test` and table column `nam` like `select * from  test 
where nam > reverse(nam) and nam in (select reverse(nam) from test)`. But I do not know how to delete them, since it is not allowed to reference the table you want to delete in a where-clause. Maybe you can save them and delete with the next step.

Comment: You say remove multiple rows, but your example has none. What steps have you taken? Please edit your question, as it is vague.
Have you considered a group by and using a DENSE_RANK such that the duplicate column is number 2 or greater?

Comment: your table have an id as primary key?

Answer (score 1):

This query joins the table with itself. The `WHERE` condition ensures t2 only holds the values to delete (ie. it will delete `ca` but not `ac`).

```
DELETE t2.*
FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.letters<t2.letters AND REVERSE(t1.letters)=t2.letters;
```

If you want to see what values would be deleted, just replace `DELETE` with  `SELECT` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Delete from test22 a where (select count(1) from test22 b where id =a.id or id=reverse(a.id)) >1 and rowid <> (select min ( rowid) from test22 c where c.id=a.id or c.id =reverse (a.id ))

Suppose test22 is the table and column contains duplicate values is id